# Applying for a position via LinkedIn

Tags: job-search, applications, linkedin

if you apply for a job via LinkedIn (by clicking on "Easy Apply"), which simply sends your attached resume and your LinkedIn profile to the employer, is there a different expectation of a follow-up? Normally, I'd send an email to the hiring agent or similarly situated individual, but I'm not sure if there is a different expectation on the Easy Apply feature of LinkedIn. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference - in fact, one of the benefits of using the Easy Apply feature is that they don't need to provide an e-mail account for candidates to follow-up (so they end up receiving less messages per candidate).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I want to clarify. Normally, after, say, a week or so, I would send a follow up email. So If there is no difference, that would mean I should email. However, it sounds like you're saying don't send one. Sorry if I'm missing something I your message.

Comment: @A.fm. You can "message them" in linked in if you want to follow up.  It's just the social media form of the email version, process isn't so much different, just the method of execution...

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment - I hate to sound nitpicky, but I'm gonna try and get one degree more particular here: I'm trying to figure out if such follow-up is a "thing" on LinkedIn job applications. In other words, I see it as an expected necessity when applying in a traditional manner via email or USAJOBS or other online platform. However, I don't know if it is expected or even so much as desired by employers who post positions over LinkedIn. Perhaps my confusion is because LinkedIn sort of straddles the boundary between personal social media and professional tool in my view.

Comment: Yes, you understood it ;) In My Very Humble Opinion, there is little point on sending a follow up message, as this is going to make little difference in the chances of being selected for an interview (I will call you if you are a strong candidate/if your look better on your resume/CV than other applicants; not because you are chasing me after a week).

Answer (score 1):

I'm in agreement with Carrdelling - with a follow-up thought..

Personally, I am always impressed when a candidate applies and seeks me out to send a PM via Linkedin. Even if it is to touch base and making sure the application made it my way. This is especially useful when HR departments screen or drop the ball on forwarding over resumes.

As for an expectation - No, not really. These are changing times of how people land a job and it isn't as black and white as perceived.

Good luck!